# Gdiplus on C++ configuration for binary image?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, mfc, gdi+

Is there any setting that I can set the color of the GDIPlus Graphics method or Bitmap method only indicates black and white color (0,0,0/255,255,255) for binary image? I've already tried colorpalette option (getPalette / setPalette) of bitmap class but it doesnt work at all.

I've accessed to the image itself but it doesn't work either. please note that image itself.

```
    for (int bufidx = 0; bufidx < m_BufferSize; bufidx++)
                    {
                        if (m_pImage[BINARY_VID][bufidx] > m_Threshold)
                        {
                            m_pImage[BINARY_VID][bufidx] = 255;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            m_pImage[BINARY_VID][bufidx] = 0;
                        }
                    } // Algorithm for thresholding image
```

this is the code that changes data itself. m_buffersize is size of the image (width * height)

m_pImage[BINARY_VID]is the data itself that has 0~255 value 8-bit data. data is from the camera module.

```
    m_pBitmap[vidType]->LockBits(&rc, 0, PixelFormat8bppIndexed, &bitmapdata);
    memcpy(bitmapdata.Scan0, m_pImage[vidType], m_BufferSize);
    m_pBitmap[vidType]->UnlockBits(&bitmapdata);
```

and it's the part that I convert it to Bitmap method

```
int paletteSize = m_pBitmap[vidType]->GetPaletteSize();
ColorPalette* pPalette = new ColorPalette[paletteSize];
m_pBitmap[vidType]->GetPalette(pPalette, paletteSize);
// gets palette info of bitmap image to set color info of the bitmap
switch (vidType)
{
case NORMAL_VID:
case ROI_VID:
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pPalette->Count; i++)
    {
        pPalette->Entries[i] = Color::MakeARGB(255, i, i, i);
    }
    m_pBitmap[vidType]->SetPalette(pPalette);
    break;
    // Normal video || ROI video color set
case BINARY_VID:
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pPalette->Count; i++)
    {
        if (i > m_Threshold)
        {
            pPalette->Entries[i] = Color::MakeARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        else
        {
            pPalette->Entries[i] = Color::MakeARGB(255, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    }
    m_pBitmap[vidType]->SetPalette(pPalette);
    break;

default:
    AfxMessageBox(TEXT("vidtype error : on converting palette!"));
    delete[] pPalette;
    return;
    break;
}
delete[] pPalette;
MemoryLeakCheck();
```

and this is the part that I use for converting color.

and this is the result image that I get. I just don't know why I have gray noise on the binary image that only has data of 0 or 255.

[image: Binary Image with gray noise]

Comment: The image provided doesn't allow us to see the true source for the image data. Please upload an image using a lossless format (e.g. PNG, although I'm not sure whether imgur will convert them to JPEG for you).